# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ViewController:>) has no segue with identifier '''

Tags: ios

[image]> 2014-09-20 18:04:45.564 storyboard_demo[6919:60b] nested push

> animation can result in corrupted navigation bar 2014-09-20
>   18:04:45.921 storyboard_demo[6919:60b] Finishing up a navigation
>   transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might
>   get corrupted. 2014-09-20 18:04:46.442 storyboard_demo[6919:60b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with identifier
>   'third''
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ed1e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0156c8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   UIKit
>
>   0x0034d48c -[UIViewController
>   shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0     3   storyboard_demo
>
>   0x0000254e -[secondViewController btn_second:] + 110  4
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157e880 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77  5   UIKit
>
>   0x0022e3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108    6
>
>   UIKit                               0x0022e345 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61    7   UIKit
>
>   0x0032fbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66  8   UIKit
>
>   0x0032ffc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577    9
>
>   UIKit                               0x0032f243 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641    10  UIKit
>
>   0x0026dddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852    11  UIKit
>
>   0x0026e9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117  12  UIKit
>
>   0x002405f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242  13  UIKit
>
>   0x0022a353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455     14  CoreFoundation 
>   0x0177677f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  15  CoreFoundation                      0x0177610b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235  16  CoreFoundation                      0x017931ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x017929d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x017927eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   19  GraphicsServices
>   0x037e15ee GSEventRunModal + 192  20  GraphicsServices
>   0x037e142b GSEventRun + 104   21  UIKit
>   0x0022cf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225   22  storyboard_demo
>   0x00002e4d main + 141     23  libdyld.dylib
>   0x01e3470d start + 1  24  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

(lldb) [image]

Comment: actualy u need to try the segue b/w first to last or first to second

Comment: i need first to second and second to first to last

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps.

`btn_second:` can post a notification that it has been pressed and then return to 'first'.  'first' receives the notification and sets a flag.  In `viewWillAppear`, 'first' checks the flag and does a 'third' segue if it's set.